# Spring, JSON Input calling another application, values are not sent

Tags: json, spring

I have a application that need to communicate with another application.

In the first application I mentioned it as:

```
public List<ContactsBO> getZingyContactsByCompanyId(int companyId) throws Exception {
    String url="http://localhost:8080/ZingyApp/getContactsToBSAByAccountId";
    URL object=new URL(url);
    JSONObject account = new JSONObject();
    String accountId = "58fd8c58abced355f69bf0bb";
    account.put("accountId", accountId);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) object.openConnection();
    conn.setConnectTimeout(50000);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
    wr.write(account.toString());
    wr.flush();
    os.close();

    String json_response = "";
    BufferedReader br = null;

    if (conn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
        br = new BufferedReader(new
        InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    } else {
        br = new BufferedReader(new
        InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream()));
    }
    String text = "";
    while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
        json_response += text;
    }
    String contacts = json_response;
    System.out.println("Contacts:"+contacts);

    return null;
}
```

In second application I am trying to get the parameter `accountId`, which I set to a `JSON` object.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getContactsToBSAByAccountId",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<Contacts> getContactsByAccountId(@ModelAttribute("accountId") String accountId) {
    System.out.println("Inside Account Details:"+accountId);
    List<Contacts> contacts=salesContactService.getContactsByAccountId("58fd8c58abced355f69bf0bb");
    return contacts;
}
```

Here `accountId` is `null`.

When I changed `@RequestParams`, the method itself is not getting called, and I got `400 error`, when I change to `@ModelAttribute` only it gets called but values are not getting post.

Can someone give a suggestion on this one?

Comment: Try `@RequestBody Map<String, Object> objectMap` instead of `ModelAttribute` and get from map like `String accountId = (String)objectMap.get("accountId")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@RequestBody Map objectMap instead of ModelAttribute and get from map like String accountId = (String)objectMap.get("accountId")

This worked for me.